# In-universe, is information on Yoda's species kept secret from others?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, yoda

Common knowledge, it is, that Yoda's species, its homeworld, name etc. are never mentioned in Star Wars media. In the films, we only ever see two of their kind, Yoda himself and Yaddle. As far as I know, even in the books, or in video games when others appear, they never disclose any information about their kind.

*In-universe* however, is there any evidence that members of Yoda's species are deliberately withholding this information from others, or is just merely hidden from us viewers / readers? I'm happy to take answers from Legends or Canon.

Comment: Not sure if you're looking for just canon or EU answers (or legends or whatever it's called now), but in the Heir to the Empire trilogy there is a line about Luke searching all known databases for information on a species like Yoda's and turning up nothing.

Comment: @Darren I've updated the question. Would personally be looking for Legends info but would be happy to take Disney canon answers too.

Answer (score 3):

In the Legends continuity, some characters don't know Yoda's species. For example, in *Dark Force Rising*, the text notes that

> after many hours of records searches, Luke still hadn't figured out just what species Yoda had belonged to.

This is several years after Yoda's death, so it's not clear whether he would've told Luke, had it occurred to him to ask. It might be that Luke simply never found the species, or never satisfactorily picked between several similar ones. (There are millions of species in the galaxy, after all, and he has only his own recollections to go off of rather than any kind of hard medical data.)

On the other hand that information might be suppressed by Yoda's species or some third party (perhaps the Empire; since their species has often been shown to be notably Force-Sensitive, it might have fallen afoul of the Jedi purges).

The best I can say is that the other characters, at least in post-RotJ Legends works, are just as ignorant as we are; *why* this is is a mystery.

Comment: Where you say that info might have been suppressed is what I am looking to establish. Could Yoda's species, or indeed someone else, be deliberately keeping this info to themselves. This is a useful start!

Comment: That information might have been in the Jedi Library before it was destroyed in the Jedi Purges